# How to get a particular field value from json response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to call an external API system from my website.In the ajax response,I get the following data.

```
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {


["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (3) {

    ["desktop_url"]=>
    string(113) "http://landing.beta.learning.social/remote?token=a_token_value"

    ["mobile_url"]=>
    string(115) "http://m.landing.beta.learning.social/remote?token=a_token_value"

  }
}
```

I need to get the value of the `desktop_url` field from this response.So that I can redirect page with the url from that field.I have tried with the following code.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: path, 
  data: "email=" + $("#email_data").val() + "&fname=" + $("#fname_data").val()+"&grade="+$("#gradeID_data").val()+
  "&lastname="+$("#lname_data").val(),
  success: function(message){
    $(message).map(function(item){console.log (item.data);});
  }
});
```

This is not working for me and giving me the following error

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: object(stdClass)#3 (3...
```

Comment: this is not a valid json array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to json encode the response from the api call

```
<?php 
$response = $api->call($params[,...]);


header('content-type:application/json');
exit(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: When I tried to encode the response in the api call ,I am getting response like this:            `string(416) ""{\"status\":\"success\",\"code\":200,\"data\":{\"token\":\"token
\",\"desktop_url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/landing.beta.learning.social\\\/remote?token=token
\",\"mobile_url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/m.landing.beta.learning.social\\\/remote?token=token
\"}}""`

Comment: try to decode the response `json_decode($response, true);` or `$responseStr= var_export($response, true);`

Comment: that looks good, you can now get the `desktop_url` from `console.log(message.data.desktop_url)` in your success function